# Lazy loading and Fetch strategies

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate 3.6 
User is an entity class 
Contact is an entity class 
User has a Set<Contact> 
The relationship is uni-directional and mapped as one-to-many. 
I have tried out the following lazy loading and fetch combinations. Here is a list of my understanding and actual results

with session.get(User.class, <some userId>) or session.load(User.class, <some userId>)

```
  lazy      fetch       result

* true      join        ignores lazy loading
*                       1 select for retrieving the User and his contacts with a left outer join
*           select      1 select for a User record
*                       1 select for all contacts of the user
*           subselect   1 select for a User record
*                       1 select for all contacts of the user
* false     join        1 select for retrieving the User and his contacts with a left outer join
*           select      1 select for a User record
*                       1 select for all contacts of the user
*           subselect   1 select for a User record
*                       1 select for all contacts of the user
```

with session.createQuery(from User)

```
   lazy     fetch           result

 * true     join            1 select for all User records
 *                          1 select for each User record to retrieve their contacts
 *                          respect lazy loading
 *                          probable n + 1
 *          select          1 select for all User records
 *                          1 select for each User record to retrieve their contacts
 *                          probable n + 1
 *          subselect       1 select for all User records
 *                          1 sub-select to retrieve all contact records in one go
 * false    join            1 select for all User records
 *                          1 select for each User record to retrieve their contacts
 *                          probable n + 1      
 *          select          1 select for all User records
 *                          1 select for each User record to retrieve their contacts
 *                          probable n + 1
 *          subselect       1 select for all User records
 *                          1 sub-select to retrieve all contact records in one go
```

Here are a few questions I have:

1. Is my understanding correct ?
2. With session.get() when lazy=true, fetch=subselect why does not Hibernate execute a subselect ? I guess this is because it is absolutely un-necessary. Am I correct ?
3. With session.get() when lazy=false, fetch=subselect why does not Hibernate execute a subselect ? It should execute one here but it does not. I wonder why ?
4. With session.createQuery() when lazy=true, fetch=join why does Hibernate lazy load ? It did not do this earlier with session.get()
5. With session.createQuery() when lazy=false, fetch=join why does not Hibernate use a join ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey guys ! I need some quick pointers on this post. Hope to receive some response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok people, after much digging this is what I can conclude. Just wanted to share my spoils with you all. If anyone feels they can add more to this, you are most welcome. Let me start with a sample data set.

```
The user table
--------------------------------------------------
USER_ID     USERNAME
--------------------------------------------------
1           User One
2           User Two
3           User Three

The contact table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CONTACTID   TITLE   FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME        CITY        COUNTRY             EMAIL                       USER_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           Mr.     Clark       Kent        New York        United States       man-of-steel@anywhere.earth     1
2           Mr.     Hank        Ketcham     Manhattan       United States       dennis-mitchell@somewhere.us    2
3           Mr.     Tony        Stark       Malibu          United States       iron-man@anywhere.earth         2
4           Mr.     Bruce       Wayne       Gotham          United States       dark-knight@gotham.us           2
```

Q2. With session.get() when lazy=true, fetch=subselect why does not Hibernate execute a subselect ? I guess this is because it is absolutely un-necessary. Am I correct ?

A2. Yes a subselect is absolutely un-necessary here. Here is what the subselect might look like

```
SELECT   
    u.USER_ID AS USER1_1_,   
    u.USERNAME AS USERNAME1_,   
    c.USER_ID AS USER15_1_1_,   
    c.CONTACTID AS CONTACTID1_,   
    c.CONTACTID AS CONTACTID0_0_,   
    c.TITLE AS TITLE0_0_,   
    c.FIRSTNAME AS FIRSTNAME0_0_,   
    c.LASTNAME AS LASTNAME0_0_,   
    c.CITY AS CITY0_0_,   
    c.COUNTRY AS COUNTRY0_0_,   
    c.EMAIL AS EMAIL0_0_,   
    FROM   
        user u,contact c   
    WHERE   
        u.USER_ID = 2  
    AND   
        c.USER_ID IN    
        (   
            SELECT USER_ID FROM user WHERE USER_ID = u.USER_ID   
        )
```

I do not see any benefit of executing a sub-select here over the current strategy of simply executing a seperate select for contact records. Infact, a subselect might be an un-necessary performance drain.

Q3. With session.get() when lazy=false, fetch=subselect why does not Hibernate execute a subselect ? It should execute one here but it does not. I wonder why ?

A3. Ok. Again here is what the sub-select might look like (exactly similar to the one above with some other id)

```
SELECT   
    u.USER_ID AS USER1_1_,   
    u.USERNAME AS USERNAME1_,   
    c.USER_ID AS USER15_1_1_,   
    c.CONTACTID AS CONTACTID1_,   
    c.CONTACTID AS CONTACTID0_0_,   
    c.TITLE AS TITLE0_0_,   
    c.FIRSTNAME AS FIRSTNAME0_0_,   
    c.LASTNAME AS LASTNAME0_0_,   
    c.CITY AS CITY0_0_,   
    c.COUNTRY AS COUNTRY0_0_,   
    c.EMAIL AS EMAIL0_0_,   
    FROM   
        user u,contact c   
    WHERE   
        u.USER_ID = 3  
    AND   
        c.USER_ID IN    
        (   
            SELECT USER_ID FROM user WHERE USER_ID = u.USER_ID   
        )
```

As you can see this will not yield any records since USER_ID=3 does not have any contact records. That defeats the whole purpose of doing session.get() for a User record wherein get() will return null inspite of having a valid User record in the table. So again, a seperate select for contact records is the only way out.

Q4. With session.createQuery() when lazy=true, fetch=join why does Hibernate lazy load ? It did not do this earlier with session.get()

Q5. With session.createQuery() when lazy=false, fetch=join why does not Hibernate use a join ?

Ans. My current understanding says that this maybe simply because Hibernate does not want to end up firing a join which selects a huge data set (comprising all User records and their Contact records) and loading a huge collection in-memory.